# HTML to SQL sending data while using POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

After setting local server, I want to send data to `SQL server` from `HTML page`. I'm using `C#`, `ASP.NET`. But the problem is, while I'm using post method, it just showing me blank result without sending `string` input properly to my `mssql` server.

Below is part of my `Write.aspx` file, which mainly takes info from users through
`HTML` text input. And I used post method to deal with info in `Write_Check.aspx` (actually in behind code, `Write_Check.aspx.cs`)

```
<%@ Page Language = "C#" AutoEventWireup = "true" 
CodeFile = "Write.aspx.cs" Inherits = "Article_Write" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script language = "javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id = "form1" method = "post" action = "Write_Check.aspx">
        <center>
            <table width = "100%" border = "0" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "3">
                <tbody><tr align = "left">
                    <td colspan = "3">
                        <h2>Write Article</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align = "left">
                    <td width = "100px">
                        Writer
                    </td>
                    <td width = "600px">
                        <input type = "text" id = "writername" name = writer_name />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

and my `Write_Check.aspx` is just one line.

```
<%@ Page Language = "C#" AutoEventWireup = "true" CodeFile = "Write_Check.aspx.cs" Inherits = "Save_Check" %>
```

and this is my `Write_Check.aspx.cs`. `CWebBase` is just a collection of methods for db connection so that I can use it easily for other cs files as well.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Save_Check : CWebBase
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name, password, title, content;
        //find form name
        name = Request.Form["writer_name"];
        password = Request.Form["password_check"];
        title = Request.Form["title_check"];
        content = Request.Form["content_check"];

        CDatabase _db = new CDatabase();

        string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.article (writerName, passwords, title, content) values('"
            + name + "','" + password + "','" + title + "','" + content + "')";

        _db.ExecuteSQL(sql);
        _db.Dispose();

        Response.Redirect("List.aspx");

    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the post method I used here work properly.

Comment: That's Save_Check not Write_Check, is it a typo?

Comment: Oh yes it is a typo. Sorry for that.

Comment: You forgot to add the runat="server" tag for your form. Check [w3 tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp) for more info.

Comment: I do not think that's the only problem. I actually tried the runat = "server" before I upload this question but didn't work

Comment: Try it simple first,  <form runat="server"> without all the parameters and see what happens.

Comment: Still It does not show me the result got from the SQL DB

Comment: Try this: enter `'; drop table article; --` in the content field...

Comment: Now read this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, from what i can see you're not actually submiting the form (not in the code you've posted anyway).

 In order to see the values in code behind you have to submit the form, by clicking a button (or anything else you want).

For example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
//data to submit
<asp:Button id="button1" Text="Click me!" runat="server" OnClick="submit" />
</form>
```

After the form is submitted you can check the values just like you tried:   
`name = Request.Form["writer_name"];`